# Javascript : on click check boxes adding divs dynamically with pure java script not Jquery

Tags: javascript

I am beginner for java script.
I have three check boxes on my page with different ids. when I checked first check box I need to show one div. when I checked second check box include first check box , I need to split one div to two divs. As well as when i checked three boxes split one div to three divs.
**I need to add all these divs dynamically with java script.**

observe the below image and same like i need

[image]

Please help me to achieve this with simple java script code not with Jquery.

Comment: Yes, please post code and highlight the area you are having a problem in. StackOverflow isn't a place where you can have other people write your code...

Comment: I need a new car ...

Comment: @Teemu if you say what you need then please with a little more effort and explain exactly what car you want! Which color and don't forget to mention the rims, it's all important to know and where should we ship it to???

Answer (score 2):

this took a bit of coding ;)

basically you want to append a div to the wrapper when you check a box, and remove it when you uncheck the box. Every time the DOM is changed I am running a setWidth function to apply a class used in the css to correctly position the boxes within the wrapper

checkboxes and wrapper to append the divs

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

css

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cols-1 {
    width: 100%;
}

.cols-2 {
    width: 50%;
}

.cols-3 {
    width: 33%;
}
```

JS

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    var checkbox = checkboxes[i];

    checkbox.addEventListener('change', changed);
}

function changed(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    var num = el.value;
    var checked = el.checked;

    if (checked) {
        addBox(num);
    } else {
        removeBox(num)
    }
}

function addBox(num) {
    var box = document.createElement('div');
    box.className = 'box';
    box.id = 'box-' + num;
    wrapper.appendChild(box);
    setWidth();
}

function removeBox(num) {
    var box = document.getElementById('box-' + num);
    wrapper.removeChild(box);
    setWidth();
}

function setWidth() {
    var children = wrapper.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var i = 0, length = children.length;

    for (i; i < length; i++) {
        children[i].className = 'box cols-' + length;
    }
}
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4hrp0qc8/1/

Comment: Thanks Joe Fitter . This is great.